# Значение слова "горелом"

Tags: значение-слов, общие-вопросы

Горелом (сущ). Это деревья, поваленные в результате пожара?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Честно говоря, найти это слово в викисловаре мне не удалось найти, но, как мне кажется, Вы совершенно правы - логично предположить, что горелом - это именно обгорелый и поваленный лес.

Comment: Ну, да. Если "бурелом" - это деревья, поваленные бурей, то "горелом" - это деревья, поваленные огнем (горением). Хотя я никогда не слышала этого слова.